# Find two subarrays with equal weighted average

Tags: algorithm

We are given an array A of integers. I want to find 2 contiguous subarrays of the largest length(both subarrays must be equal in length) that have the same weighted average. The weights are the positions in the subarray. For example

> A=41111921111119
>   Subarrays:: (11119) and (11119)

Ive tried to find the weighted average of all subarrays by DP and then sorting them columnwise to find 2 with same length.But I cant proceed further and my approach seems too vague/bruteforce.I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no....one of my friends asked me this.It was some question from a programming site(maybe Topcoder/Codeforces).

Comment: Uhm, so what are the weights? You need a list of weights if you're talking about weighted averages.

Comment: the weights are the positions in the subarray.For example 11119 will have weighted average 1*1+2*1+3*1+4*1+5*9/15=3.66

Comment: Can the integers be negative? zero? other constraints?

Comment: I guess they will be positive only

Comment: Can the 2 sub-arrays overlap at all?

Answer (score 0):

The first step should be to sort the array. Any pairs of equal values can then be identified and factored out. The remaining numbers will all be different, like this:

2, 3, 5, 9, 14, 19 ... etc

The next step would be to compare pairs to their center:

2 + 5  == 2 * 3 ?
3 + 9  == 2 * 5 ?
5 + 14 == 2 * 9 ?
9 + 19 == 2 * 14 ?

The next step is to compare nested pairs, meaning if you have A B C D, you compare A+D to B+C. So for the above example it would be:

2+9 == 3+5 ?
3+15 == 5+9 ?
5+19 == 9+14 ?

Next you would compare triples to the two inside values:

2 + 3 + 9  == 3 * 5 ?
2 + 5 + 9  == 3 * 3 ?
3 + 5 + 14 == 3 * 9 ? 
3 + 9 + 14 == 3 * 5 ?
5 + 9 + 19 == 3 * 14 ?
5 + 14 + 19 == 3 * 9 ?

Then you would compare pairs of triples:

2 + 3 + 19 == 5 + 9 + 14 ?
2 + 5 + 19 == 3 + 9 + 14 ?
2 + 9 + 19 == 3 + 5 + 14 ?

and so on. There are different ways to do the ordering. One way is to create an initial bracket, for example, given A B C D E F G H, the initial bracket is ABGH versus CDEF, ie the outside compared to the center. Then switch values according to the comparison. For example, if ABGH > CDEF, then you can try all switches where the left value is greater than the right value. In this case G and H are greater than E and F, so the possible switches are:

G <-> E
G <-> F
H <-> E
H <-> F
GH <-> EF

Answer (score 0):

First, as the length of the two subarray must be equal, you can consider the length from 1 to n step by step.

For length i, you can calculate the weighted sum of every subarray in a total complexity of O(n). Then sort the sums to determine if there's an equal pair.

Because you sort n times the time would be O(n^2 log n) while the space is O(n).

Maybe I just repeated your solution mentioned in the question? But I don't think it can be optimized any more...